# "Wrong number of indices inside [];expected 2" error for two-dimensional array in C#

Tags: c#, arrays, multidimensional-array, indexing, indices

Hi I am a beginner c# learner, I did something wrong here as I know, but can't figure out where, anybody knows?

```
namespace translateTelNum
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        String originalContent = "";
        originalContent = box1.Text.ToUpper();

        char[,] charGroup = new char[,]
       {
        {'A','B','C' }, 
        {'D','E','F' },              
        {'G','H','I' }, 
        {'J','K','L' }, 
        {'M','N','O' },
        {'P','R','S' }, 
        {'T','U','V' }, 
        {'W','X','Y' } 
       };

        String numbers = "";

        for (int i = 1; i <= originalContent.Length; i++)
        {
            for (int a = 1; a <= charGroup.Length; a++)
            {
                for (int b = 1; b <= charGroup[a].Length; b++)
                {
                    if (originalContent[i] == charGroup[a][b])
                    {
                        numbers += a + 2;
                    }
                }
            }
            if (i == 2 && i== 7)
            {
                numbers += "-";
            }
        }

        Console.WriteLine(numbers);
    }
}
}
```

---

Error "Wrong number of indices inside [];expected 2" for the following lines:

```
for (int b = 1; b <= charGroup[a].Length; b++)
    if (originalContent[i] == charGroup[a][b])
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of using

```
for (int a = 1; a <= charGroup.Length; a++)
{
    for (int b = 1; b <= charGroup[a].Length; b++)
    {
        if (originalContent[i] == charGroup[a][b])
```

You should use

```
for (int a = 1; a <= charGroup.GetLength(0); a++)
{
    for (int b = 1; b <= charGroup.GetLength(1); b++)
    {
        if (originalContent[i] == charGroup[a,b])
```

There are two things that need to be changed.

First, instead of using `charGroup.Length` and `charGroup[a].Length` you should use method `GetLength(dimension)` to get the length of specific dimension. So in this case in order to get the number of rows you should use `GetLength(0)` and to get the number of columns you should use `GetLength(1)`. See [documentation of `GetLength` on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.getlength(v=vs.110).aspx)

Second, C# multidimensional arrays are accessed by `array[index1, index2, ..., indexN]` and not by `array[index1][index2] ... [indexN]`. See [documentation on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2yd9wwz4.aspx)

Also keep in mind that indexes of Arrays in C# start from 0, so most likely your loop should start at 0 instead of 1:

```
for (int a = 0; a < charGroup.GetLength(0); a++)
{
    for (int b = 0; b < charGroup.GetLength(1); b++)
    {
        if (originalContent[i] == charGroup[a,b])
```